# GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE Parsing XML File

Tags: java, android, xml

With the following code I parse a xml file from remote server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //  HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

On android 2.2 phone device this code works well, but testing on android 4.4 tablet device LogCat shows the following error:

```
W/System.err(4820): [DEBUG] GbaRequest - GbaRequest: Constructor Called 222 userAgent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
W/System.err(4820): [DEBUG] NafRequest - NafRequest: NafRequest constructor===useragent Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
I/System.out(4820): Thread-1(ApacheHTTPLog):Reading from variable values from setDefaultValuesToVariables
I/System.out(4820): Thread-1(ApacheHTTPLog):isShipBuild true
I/System.out(4820): Thread-1(ApacheHTTPLog):SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
I/System.out(4820): main calls detatch()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016338/warning-error-meaning-gbarequest-gbarequest-constructor-called-222-useragen) I found a question with same error but without answers.

Could you help me, please, to understand this kind of error.

Thank you.

Comment: Solved running code inside AsyncTask.

Comment: I wrote the original post and I'm still unable to figure this out.  When you say you used an AsyncTask, where exactly?  I use AsyncTasks to run all my queries and I still receive this.

Answer (score 0):

here my working code:

```
// UPDATE
private class UPD_Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(youractivity.this);
pDialog.setTitle("UPDATE");
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... Url) {
    try{
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL1); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM
nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
if(nodes!=null){upd1=true;}
    }catch (Exception e) { Log.d("parser error", "parser error");
    upd1=false;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
{
    if (upd1==false){TV1.setText("update error");}
    else {ResultUPD();}
}
pDialog.dismiss();
}}

private void ResultUPD(){
datasource.open();
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
row_number = parser.getValue(e, "row_number");
....}
datasource.close();
if(nodes.getLength()>0){TV1.setText("update ok");}
}
```